# Creating multiple bitcoin receipt wallet

Tags: wallet, address, private-key, electrum, seed

Suppose I want to send 10 000 sats to 10 different "receipt" address so that I own the 10 private keys associated with these addresses and can distribute them, the fact that the receiver know that I know these private key does not matter

I was thinking about simply creating an electrum wallet, send 10 000 sats to 10 addresses from this wallet, then export the private key of those 10 wallet on a text file and then give them one by one, the receiver being able to then create his own wallet and private key to store safely his coin whenever he want.

Could this work, and is it safe ? when I go to export on electrum to see the private key I read "Exposing a single private key can compromise your entire wallet" I could create 10 wallet but it is tedious and what if I want to do more, or is there a better method ( without lightning network ) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Warning: I don't know your use case, but in general I strongly recommend against ever giving anyone a private key. Even if in this situation they trust you enough, it is bad practice, and without good understanding I believe the risk of making people comfortable with the idea of sharing private keys likely has far worse negative than positive effects. Private keys are supposed to be private.

The reason Electrum gives this warning is because when someone knows an xpub (extended public key) + a private key corresponding to any public key derived from that xpub, they can compute the private key for *every* public key derived from the same xpub. This can be counteracted by using hardened derivation (unsure if Electrum supports that), or by having independently created keys (separate "wallets" for every key).